# How to change __init__ to Tk() windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone help me to understand the window code? Im trying to make all the objects run in a Toplevel() function instead of a new instance of Tkinter because that doesn't work launching it from another program. Theres no window = Tk() function anywhere just **init** and frame.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter.filedialog   import asksaveasfilename

from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel          

def text_edit() :
   class Quitter(Frame):                        
    def __init__(self, parent=None):          
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        widget = Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    def quit(self):
        ans = askokcancel('Verify exit', "Really quit?")
        if ans: Frame.quit(self)


class ScrolledText(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, text='', file=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)               
        self.makewidgets()
        self.settext(text, file)
    def makewidgets(self):
        sbar = Scrollbar(self)
        text = Text(self, relief=SUNKEN)
        sbar.config(command=text.yview)                  
        text.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)           
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)                   
        text.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)     
        self.text = text
    def settext(self, text='', file=None):
        if file: 
            text = open(file, 'r').read()
        self.text.delete('1.0', END)                   
        self.text.insert('1.0', text)                  
        self.text.mark_set(INSERT, '1.0')              
        self.text.focus()                                
    def gettext(self):                               
        return self.text.get('1.0', END+'-1c')         



class SimpleEditor(ScrolledText):                        
    def __init__(self, parent=None, file=None): 
        frm = Frame(parent)
        frm.pack(fill=X)
        Button(frm, text='Save',  command=self.onSave).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(frm, text='Cut',   command=self.onCut).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(frm, text='Paste', command=self.onPaste).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(frm, text='Find',  command=self.onFind).pack(side=LEFT)
        Quitter(frm).pack(side=LEFT)
        ScrolledText.__init__(self, parent, file=file) 
        self.text.config(font=('courier', 9, 'normal'))
    def onSave(self):
        filename = asksaveasfilename()
        if filename:
            alltext = self.gettext()                      
            open(filename, 'w').write(alltext)          
    def onCut(self):
        text = self.text.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)        
        self.text.delete(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)           
        self.clipboard_clear()              
        self.clipboard_append(text)
    def onPaste(self):                                    
        try:
            text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
            self.text.insert(INSERT, text)
        except TclError:
            pass                                      
    def onFind(self):
        target = askstring('SimpleEditor', 'Search String?')
        if target:
            where = self.text.search(target, INSERT, END)  
            if where:                                    
                print (where)
                pastit = where + ('+%dc' % len(target))   
               #self.text.tag_remove(SEL, '1.0', END)     
                self.text.tag_add(SEL, where, pastit)     
                self.text.mark_set(INSERT, pastit)         
                self.text.see(INSERT)                    
                self.text.focus()                        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        SimpleEditor(file=sys.argv[1]).mainloop()   
    except IndexError:
        SimpleEditor().mainloop()
```

Comment: what is your question? This code opens a file provided as an argument in a SimpleEditor windows (or blank editor if no filename provided). But it is unclear what's your problem. Maybe you should just read some basic tutorials on Tk and OOP in Python?

Comment: Code with questions should be cut to the minimum that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Well right now, i have a program that is made to launch other scripts. So when i click "Text Editor", i want it to open this up but when i did that, it tries to open a new tkinter instance which doesn't work.

Comment: So how can I change this to make a "Toplevel" window instead of a new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adapt to Tkinter as it was written to be used (or write your own which is beyond me), instead of trying to pound it into some preconceived form.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial

class OpenToplevels():
    """ open and close additional Toplevels with a button
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.button_ctr=0
        but=tk.Button(self.root, text="Open a Toplevel",
                     command=self.open_another)
        but.grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit Tkinter", bg="red",
                 command=self.root.quit).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def close_it(self, id):
        id.destroy()

    def open_another(self):
        self.button_ctr += 1
        id = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        id.title("Toplevel #%d" % (self.button_ctr))
        tk.Button(id, text="Close Toplevel #%d" % (self.button_ctr),
                 command=partial(self.close_it, id),
                 bg="orange").grid(row=1, column=0)


Ot=OpenToplevels()
```